# Boot with Ubuntu livecd gives an error message before proceeding to a grub style menu, is it safe to proceed with installation?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

Error message is

```
Could not open "\EFI\BOOT\fallback.efi": 14
```

I then get to a grub menu with four options: Try Ubuntu without installing, Install Ubuntu, OEM install, Check disc for defects.

I have done the try ubuntu method, and the livecd ubuntu seems to work as normal.

I am just worried about whether or not this would have implications for an EFI (UEFI) install, as the [Ubuntu UEFI Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) seems to suggest that I would need to install in EFI mode, as my Windows 8 is installed as EFI (and I will be dual booting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could not open "\EFI\BOOT\fallback.efi": 14

Doesnot cause any problems.After installing ubuntu try to turn off secureboot.

or

Try to install Ubuntu in EFI mode.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Installing_Ubuntu_in_EFI_mode

Comment: To clarify: Don't panic when seeing `Could not open "\EFI\BOOT\fallback.efi": 14`, just wait a couple of seconds and the GRUB bootloader menu should show up.